# Telerik Reporting Problems

Tags: asp.net, telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting

Anyone else using this?  I've just installed it, documentation is hidden somewhere, and so far it's not doing to well.  It's Toolbox tab is missing, and when I add the items manually, they disappear again seconds later.  I have managed to get one report done, but nowhere can I find how to make the viewer show it, without a very long winded error about not finding a certain path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark and Martin already pointed out Telerik support is second to none, so you would surely get help in their forums/support threads. I'm currently working with their Reporting product and honestly I have not experienced any problems so far. I've read that they had problems with the toolbox in x64 bit machines, but it has been resolved in the latest service pack, so you might want to make sure you are using the latest version first. However adding the items manually to the toolbox would definitely work and if you are having problem with that too, it sounds more like a Visual Studio problem to me. Also looking at their [system requirements](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting/resources/system-requirements.aspx), VS Express editions are not supported, so this might be the case as well.
Looking through their help, I find a whole section about their reportviewer and how to use it - check it out: http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/aspnetreportviewerembedding.html

Comment: I had to run VS in admin mode to get the telerik toolbar tab to appear, but then it did, all on its own steam, and things got better from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the complete documentation and tutorials online in [the support section](http://www.telerik.com/support/documentation-and-tutorials.aspx) of their site. If this does not help, ask in the [forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx). And since you have valid license, you can also create a [support ticket](http://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets.aspx).

I can't comment on the reporting component, since I have never used it. But I do use the ASP.NET controls and from that I can tell you that you will usually get help very quickly (especially when creating a support ticket).

Answer (score 0):

Telerik offers many useful controls and is generally quite conscientious about their code and support.  You're likely to have more luck on their site's forums.

With that being said, I found their reporting tool to be quite buggy and unusable.

Comment: +1 I use telerik controls and they are good at resolving questions, and Profk can get plenty of help seeing video Tutorials and reading the docmentation